# facebook lead ads tool no access-control-allow-origin

Tags: facebook

The Facebbok Lead Ads Tool stopped working 2 days ago for me.

I now get this in the console log: Failed to load https://www.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing/form-validation/?dpr=2&__a=1: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://developers.facebook.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Anyone else having this issue? Is there any work around? I have tried all browsers.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: That does not help. There is no bug reported that I can find and If I try to report, then the Lead ads tool is not even on the list.

Comment: Facebook is now escalating it. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Facebook fixed it today.